# Keeping session start code as an include

Tags: php, include, sessionid

first time posting here so be gentle :)

On my web pages I have the usual session start and there is quite a few pages.

Is there any reason why I can't just put all my session starting code in a separate PHP file and then first up call it as an include?

Is this doable? Is it considered safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure -- just remember that your PHP file cannot output any text to the client prior to `session_start()`, since session_start() typically outputs an HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

> Why I can't just put all my session starting code in a separate PHP
>   file and then first up call it as an include?

Why not, you should do that, this is nothing unsafe. In fact, most php frameworks only have `index.php` as the frontend entry, and there is only one place to have `session_start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Often the page is divided in main.php which includes:

header.php // with includes and meta tags and styles dynamically set 
and footer.php

When you place your session_start in the header this is a common way of doing it.